# changing the value of a list with a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pre defined list which I want to be a "new" list when the function ends.

for example

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3]
```

What I want is for this function:

```
extend_list_x(x, y)
```

to make this

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I have tried returning joined_list, but I cannot change the value of x

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3]

def extend_list_x(x, y):
    joined_list = [*y, *x]
    global x 
    x = joined_list
    return x

extend_list_x(x, y)
```

at the moment this is my problem

```
SyntaxError: name 'x' is parameter and global
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, avoid `global` in functions at all costs. Functions have *parameters*. Use them (and possibly return values)
- Then, choose between *returning* a new list or *modifying* the first one:

this changes `x` in-place thanks to slice notation in the left hand:

```
def extend_list_x(x, y):
    x[:] = y+x
```

or even better, not assigning `x` fully but reusing previous `x` value using partial slice assignment. Just tell python to put the right hand contents *before* index 0 (previous elements will be shifted since the target length is < `len(y)` because it's 0):

```
def extend_list_x(x, y):
    x[:0] = y
```

call like this:

```
extend_list_x(x,y)
```

this one creates a new list and returns it, leaving `x` unchanged

```
def extend_list_x(x, y):
    return y+x
```

call like this:

```
x = extend_list_x(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since x is mutable, you don't need to use global, which is bad ;) .

```
def prepend(x,y):
    z=y+x # construct the final result and store it in a local variable
    x.clear() # global x is now []
    x.extend(z) # "copy" z in x
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new list you can simply use the addition operator:

```
def joiner(x,y):
    return x+y
```

If you want to keep the same list then you can use the list extend() method:

```
def joiner(x,y):
    return x.extend(y)
```